# Bootstrap dropdown menu open after click until long running function completes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

I have a Bootstrap dropdown that functions well, however when an item is selected from the list a function is called that takes as long as thirty seconds. The dropdown remains open until the function completes and the OnClick event exits.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-10">
  <div id="ddColor" class="dropdown">
    <h3 class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span id="ddColorChoice">Select Color</span>
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </h3>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yellow</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#ddColor").on("click", "li a ", function() {
  value = $(this).text();
  $("#ddColorChoice").text(value);
  SomeLongProcess(2000);
});


function SomeLongProcess(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to "close" the dropdown on click and then process the function?

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/JimLidel/548sLtge/)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using jQuery or another JavaScript library/framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use promises and deferreds to handle a long running process.  That way the long running process would run asynchronously, and not block the browser from responding.

Specifically, I would create a deferred to act as my "container" for the long running process.

```
var def = $.Deferred();
```

In the done event of the deferred, I would call the long running process. In this case, I'm doing a couple of other actions as well:

```
def.done(function() {
    var t = p.html() + "<br/>def resolved, calling long running process";
    p.html(t);
    console.log("def done");
    LongRunningProcess(3000);
});
```

In the click event, I would resolve my deferred that I am using to manage the long running event.  Because there is no action to do, the "done" function will immediately execute, calling the long running process.

```
$(document).on("click", "li a ", function() {
    value = $(this).text();
    el.text(value);
    def.resolve();
});
```

[You can find out more about promises here.](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

I substituted in a simple setTimeout function for an example.

```
function LongRunningProcess(ms) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var t = p.html() + "<br/>long running process done";
        p.html(t);
        console.log("long running process done");
        deferred.resolve;
    }, ms);
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

[Here is a link to the complete fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/0af5k80a/).

Comment: Can't help myself, gotta say thanks so much for a fantastic answer!